# How do I post to Twitter using Unity3D? It always throws an error

Tags: twitter, plugins, unity-game-engine

I have Integrated G+ and Facebook already to my game, but Twitter sure takes the cake for being way harder to set up for whatever reason!

First off, Twitter does not have an official plugin on their website. Their system works through authentication through their website with codes to help validate someone logging in and posting. Since nobody on the face of the internet wants to make a tutorial on how to do such a thing that is actually up to date, I am at a loss.

The best thing I can find is This plugin in the asset store which is free called "Let's Tweet In Unity"

Everyone I see with the same problem as me, Automatically say, oh yeah, this Plugin works, just gotta change this and this, and it will work! I did change this and that, error. I didn't change this and that, ERROR. I even read the description and used a "cleaned up version" some fans of the Plugin made. ERROR.

The ERROR:
http://prntscr.com/a75pv0

The Code making Error:
http://prntscr.com/a75qcp

The Code:

```
using Twitter;
using UnityEngine;

public class Demo : MonoBehaviour
{
    // You need to save access token and secret for later use.
    // You can keep using them whenever you need to access the user's Twitter account.
    // They will be always valid until the user revokes the access to your application.
    private const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_ID = "";

    private const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_SCREEN_NAME = "TwitterUserScreenName";
    private const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN = "";
    private const string PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN_SECRET = "";
    public string CONSUMER_KEY;
    public string CONSUMER_SECRET;
    public float PIN_ENTER_HEIGHT;
    public float PIN_ENTER_WIDTH;
    public float PIN_ENTER_X;
    public float PIN_ENTER_Y;
    public float PIN_INPUT_HEIGHT;
    public float PIN_INPUT_WIDTH;
    public float PIN_INPUT_X;
    public float PIN_INPUT_Y;
    public float POST_TWEET_HEIGHT;
    public float POST_TWEET_WIDTH;
    public float POST_TWEET_X;
    public float POST_TWEET_Y;
    public float TWEET_INPUT_HEIGHT;
    public float TWEET_INPUT_WIDTH;
    public float TWEET_INPUT_X;
    public float TWEET_INPUT_Y;
    public float USER_LOG_IN_HEIGHT;
    public float USER_LOG_IN_WIDTH;
    public float USER_LOG_IN_X;
    public float USER_LOG_IN_Y;

    private AccessTokenResponse m_AccessTokenResponse;

    private string m_PIN = "Please enter your PIN here.";
    private RequestTokenResponse m_RequestTokenResponse;
    private string m_Tweet = "Please enter your tweet here.";

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        LoadTwitterUserInfo();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
    }

    // GUI
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        // LogIn/Register Button
        var rect = new Rect(Screen.width * USER_LOG_IN_X,
                            Screen.height * USER_LOG_IN_Y,
                            Screen.width * USER_LOG_IN_WIDTH,
                            Screen.height * USER_LOG_IN_HEIGHT);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CONSUMER_KEY) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(CONSUMER_SECRET))
        {
            string text =
                "You need to register your game or application first.\n Click this button, register and fill CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET of Demo game object.";
            if (GUI.Button(rect, text))
            {
                Application.OpenURL("http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string text = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName))
            {
                text = m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName + "\nClick to register with a different Twitter account";
            }
            else
            {
                text = "You need to register your game or application first.";
            }

            if (GUI.Button(rect, text))
            {
                StartCoroutine(API.GetRequestToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                   OnRequestTokenCallback));
            }
        }

        // PIN Input
        rect.x = Screen.width * PIN_INPUT_X;
        rect.y = Screen.height * PIN_INPUT_Y;
        rect.width = Screen.width * PIN_INPUT_WIDTH;
        rect.height = Screen.height * PIN_INPUT_HEIGHT;

        m_PIN = GUI.TextField(rect, m_PIN);

        // PIN Enter Button
        rect.x = Screen.width * PIN_ENTER_X;
        rect.y = Screen.height * PIN_ENTER_Y;
        rect.width = Screen.width * PIN_ENTER_WIDTH;
        rect.height = Screen.height * PIN_ENTER_HEIGHT;

        if (GUI.Button(rect, "Enter PIN"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(API.GetAccessToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, m_RequestTokenResponse.Token, m_PIN,
                                              OnAccessTokenCallback));
        }

        // Tweet Input
        rect.x = Screen.width * TWEET_INPUT_X;
        rect.y = Screen.height * TWEET_INPUT_Y;
        rect.width = Screen.width * TWEET_INPUT_WIDTH;
        rect.height = Screen.height * TWEET_INPUT_HEIGHT;

        m_Tweet = GUI.TextField(rect, m_Tweet);

        // Post Tweet Button
        rect.x = Screen.width * POST_TWEET_X;
        rect.y = Screen.height * POST_TWEET_Y;
        rect.width = Screen.width * POST_TWEET_WIDTH;
        rect.height = Screen.height * POST_TWEET_HEIGHT;

        if (GUI.Button(rect, "Post Tweet"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(API.PostTweet(m_Tweet, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, m_AccessTokenResponse,
                                         OnPostTweet));
        }
    }

    private void LoadTwitterUserInfo()
    {
        m_AccessTokenResponse = new AccessTokenResponse();

        m_AccessTokenResponse.UserId = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_ID);
        m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_SCREEN_NAME);
        m_AccessTokenResponse.Token = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN);
        m_AccessTokenResponse.TokenSecret = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN_SECRET);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.Token) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.Token) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_AccessTokenResponse.TokenSecret))
        {
            string log = "LoadTwitterUserInfo - succeeded";
            log += "\n    UserId : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.UserId;
            log += "\n    ScreenName : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.ScreenName;
            log += "\n    Token : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.Token;
            log += "\n    TokenSecret : " + m_AccessTokenResponse.TokenSecret;
            Debug.Log(log);
        }
    }

    private void OnRequestTokenCallback(bool success, RequestTokenResponse response)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            string log = "OnRequestTokenCallback - succeeded";
            log += "\n    Token : " + response.Token;
            log += "\n    TokenSecret : " + response.TokenSecret;
            print(log);

            m_RequestTokenResponse = response;

            API.OpenAuthorizationPage(response.Token);
        }
        else
        {
            print("OnRequestTokenCallback - failed.");
        }
    }

    private void OnAccessTokenCallback(bool success, AccessTokenResponse response)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            string log = "OnAccessTokenCallback - succeeded";
            log += "\n    UserId : " + response.UserId;
            log += "\n    ScreenName : " + response.ScreenName;
            log += "\n    Token : " + response.Token;
            log += "\n    TokenSecret : " + response.TokenSecret;
            print(log);

            m_AccessTokenResponse = response;

            PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_ID, response.UserId);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_SCREEN_NAME, response.ScreenName);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN, response.Token);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_TWITTER_USER_TOKEN_SECRET, response.TokenSecret);
        }
        else
        {
            print("OnAccessTokenCallback - failed.");
        }
    }

    private void OnPostTweet(bool success)
    {
        print("OnPostTweet - " + (success ? "succedded." : "failed."));
    }
}
```

My intention is giving the player a special Point if they share via twitter, which means I have to also confirm that they have posted something, etc.

Comment: Can you add your code to the body of the text rather than an image of the code? It makes it easier for people to test what you are doing and help you solve your issue ;)

Comment: I just added it, but for some reason StackOverflow doesn't want to show all of it in one box? idk I tried. Its all there though,

Comment: You need to use the code formatting tools in the editor, as per my edit just now - select the code and click. There is a preview window for this express purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open using a plugin. I would recommend of using the Soomla Social Media Plugin. You can find it here: https://github.com/soomla/unity3d-profile

Updating a status on Twitter is just a simple call on Soomla. See below.

SoomlaProfile.UpdateStory(
                  Provider.TWITTER,
                  "Check out this great story by SOOMLA !",
                  "SOOMLA is 2 years young!",
                  "SOOMLA is GROWing",
                  "soomla_2_years",
                  "someLink",
                  "someLink",
                  new BadgeReward("sherriff", "Sheriff"));

Comment: I managed to fix the script to the extent of the Demo which allows me to Get a 'Pin' from twitter website, but then I have to copy it, go back to the app, paste it, the I am able to make a post? I don't get it. Doesn't twitter just ask for authorization of an app and then you can post all you want? How do I do that?